# Print LayoutRoot and Fit To Page

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am using Silverlight 5 and VB.Net.

My LayoutRoot is Width=1300.

When I print to paper or an .xps file I am losing the right hand side of the output.

How can I force Silverlight to fit to page?

My code is below. Thanks,

JT

```
Imports System.Windows.Printing

Partial Public Class Page3
    Inherits Page
    Public WithEvents pd As New PrintDocument()

Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        pd = New PrintDocument()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        pd.Print("People Framework")
    End Sub

    Private Sub pd_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pd.PrintPage
        e.PageVisual = LayoutRoot
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `PrintableArea` parameter to get your page size first.

Look at this blog post [silverlight-printing-fit-to-page](http://jacekjura.blogspot.nl/2010/11/silverlight-printing-fit-to-page.html) for a detailed answer. It's for C# but the principle is the same.